# Cast Away in Past Tense?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

What's the past tense for cast away?
Is it right to say 'I was cast away 3 months ago'?

I am a bit confused about this after reading this:
[Can "casted" be the past tense of "cast"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94565/can-casted-be-the-past-tense-of-cast)

Comment: What did you find when you looked up the verb "cast" in a dictionary?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94565/can-casted-be-the-past-tense-of-cast @sumelic

Comment: thanks for the interesting link. Please include background info like that in your question; it helps people write a more useful answer. Does this mean that you are wondering if we would say "I was cast away" or "I was casted away?"

Comment: Yes. You hit the bull's eye. What's the right way to say it? @sumelic

Comment: Note that "I was cast away 3 months ago" implies that you were lost on a deserted island or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. "Cast" is an irregular verb that is written and pronounced exactly the same in all tenses.

Here's a somewhat silly, yet very useful, article on irregular verbs, featuring a complete list of those:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_irregular_verbs

Answer (score 0):

*Is it right to say 'I was cast away 3 months ago'?*

It's grammatically okay ("cast" being fine in all the tenses), but logically it is not a very compelling sentence (unless you have recently returned to civilisation and you are describing what happened to you).

Also "3" should be "three" in most written forms.